# Remoting in spring: es.interop.dto.NameDto cannot be cast to es.interop.dto.NameDto

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, interop, rmi

I have a Multi-Project gradle + spring-boot configuration. There is a ":interop" project that contains common classes and there are other two projects, ":backend" and ":frontend" that include this other project as dependency, like this:

```
compile project(":interop")
```

I execute an RMI call from ":frontend" to ":backend". If I execute .gradlew build and run the resulting jars from command line I get no error. But if I run them directly in eclipse I get the following error in ":frontend":

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: es.interop.dto.NameDto cannot be cast to es.interop.dto.NameDto
```

There are only two copy of NameDto.class in file system.

```
$ find ~ -name NameDto.class
./interop/bin/es/interop/dto/NameDto.class
./interop/build/classes/main/es/interop/dto/NameDto.class
```

The .classpath includes the project as:

```
$ grep interop frontend/.classpath 
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/interop"/>
```

Any glues are welcome.

**edit** The service definition is:

```
public interface NameService {
    List<NameDto> findAll();
    NameDto create(String value);
}
```

**edit** I am using Dev-Tools. It is causing the problems:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.3.0.RELEASE")
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot's DevTools?

Comment: Andy: You are right. I removed it and it is working. But maybe that is not the best solution. I redo the question so others can benefit. Can you give the answer accordingly?

Comment: Hi Andy, I am answering my own newbie question. Please provide a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Dev-Tools reloads always on startup, even without changing the code once started. In this reload, probably, bytecode of NameDto is modified in backend and frontend so two different versions classes appear.

Removing Dev-Tools dependency worked for me.

Looking for a better answer in Dev-Tools docs it seems that using Dev-Tools in addition to a java-agent such as JRebel or SpringLoaded prevents reload on start and, therefore, it should work.